# How do I add Arduino libraries to Eclipse Project?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, arduino, intel-edison

how do I add Arduino libraries to Eclipse Project? I just started playing with Intel Edison and have a Grove developer kit with an LCD that I can't use, because the library is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings
You can add a library under the appropriate compiler with -l and you can include directories for headers with -I under C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols under the includes tab.

Comment: that is -l (lowercase L for libraries) and -I (uppercase i for headers)

Answer (score 2):

This is an update as of 8/12/2018.
The process has changed since 2014.
It may change again.

```
This is my configuration:
Ubuntu (18.04)
Eclipse: Photon (4.9)
C++ Oxygen 2 (9.3)
Arduino CDT   (3.0)
```

There is on official way to add a library member.

And there is a hacked way. I do not support the hacked way
I will only tell you what I have found that works
for today. No guarantees, warranties, or other legal
liabilities. No money, you get what you paid. If it
works use it. If it does not, don't bring up any problems with
the official support. There is no support for the hacked way.

The official way is to download the library members
from the website: //arduino.cc. This is made possible
by installing the Arduino CDT package from the market place.
After the install, an additional menu item is added to the
"Help" menu. It is labeled "Arduino Download Manager".
Follow the panels to the libraries tab and select "Add" option. 
Receive a list of groups. Expand a group to see the members under each group that identifies libraries that can be added to your installation.

The non-official way is to create a folder with the name
of your library. In this folder place 3 files: the library's ".h" and ".cpp"
files, and an additional "library.properties". 
An arduino library is essentially a C++ class definition.

Here is a sample of the library.propertiels contents:

library.properties:

---

```
 name=<your library name>
 version=1.0.0
 author=<your name>
 maintainer=<your name>
 sentence=<brief description>
 paragraph=<more detailed description>
 category=Private 
 url=local
 architectures=*
```

---

Notice: I named the category "Private". This will keep
all of my libraries out of the listing of standard libraries.

Copy this directory with the three files into the "/home/user/.arduinocdt/libaries/" folder.

Restart your Eclipse session (so it rebuilds the library definitions).

This installs the library but it does not mean you can use it
in your project. To have access in your project you have
to make it apart of your project.

To make it useful to your project, access the "Project" view 
(acces this view by: /window/show view/Project Explorer).
Select the project you wish to modify, and right-click on
that project. You should receive a pop-up menu which contains
an entry labeled "Properties" (at the very bottom). This will 
cause an properties panel to be displayed. In that panel 
select the "libraries" options. You should receive a list of 
all the possible categories. Expand the "Private" category, 
and place a checkmark next to your library and click "apply" 
or "apply and close".

You should now be able to add a "#include <.....h>" statement
in a member of your project (.i.e. sketch). If you make changes to your
library member, make them outside of the ".arduinocdt" directory.
shutdown eclipse; copy the new contents into the library, and
restart your eclipse session.

This is NON-OFFICIAL "hack" and I do not support this. It is just what
I found works for me. becareful it may cause problems, now or in the
future with updates or releases. Be prepared to abandon it is there
is a problem. (If you go into "Help/Arduino Download Manager/ under the
"libraries" tab you should see a list of  groups which should include
the "Private" group under that group you should see your library listed.
By selecting it and clicking "uninstall", It will remove your library
folder from the ".arduinocdt/libraries" directory. Maintaining your
libraries is your responsibility. Deleting a library will impact your
projects. Buyer be ware.

Answer (score 0):

In the hack/solution of just.a.guy the local library must be placed inside of ~/.arduinocdt directory.
To use/develop a local library on other place, a soft link to the library must be placed in two places:

```
~/.arduinocdt/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.2/libraries/SzBLib ->     
~/projects/arduino/oxmon-2500/SzBLib
~/.arduinocdt/libraries/SzBLib                                     -> 
~/projects/arduino/oxmon-2500/SzBLib
```

The structure of local library:

```
tree ~/projects/arduino/oxmon-2500/SzBLib
├── examples
│   ├── Blink13
│   │   └── Blink13.ino
├── Import
├── keywords.txt
├── library.properties
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── Blink13.cpp
    └── Blink13.h
```

SzBLib must now be selected:

[image: eclipse libraries setting]

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse 2020-03
I had to add the libraries used in my project in 2 places
a) under "Help" / "Arduino Downloads Manager" in the library tab.

b) in my project in the "project properties" dialog (right click your project and look for the properties link)
In the properties dialog in the left pane select "Libraries". Then enable ALL libraries used in your project. Toggle on the individual libraries not only the categories.